# mobile development system, sitecore vs netbiscuits

Tags: .net, sitecore, netbiscuits

do You think that Sitecore is enough to provide good solutions for mobile websites development/presentation of the content on different devices.

Or maybe its better to use netbiscuits. The best would be to combine bought but how ?

Do You have any experience with that ?

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore provides more than enough capabilities for creating modile sites, with built-in devices support and the concept of "Devices" in general.

For more previse detection you might want to use free [Mobile Device Detector module](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Mobile_Device_Detector.aspx)

I've seen Sitecore / netBiscuits integrations, but they were primarily targeted mobile applications for iOS / Android.